# (Pytorch)AssertionError: Invalid type <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I tried to retrain LoFTR(2021 CVPR paper), but I have faced some bugs. I'm a newcomer of deep-learning, please bear with me.
The full traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/LoFTR-master/train.py", line 14, in <module>
    from src.config.default import get_cfg_defaults
  File "D:\LoFTR-master\src\config\default.py", line 72, in <module>
    _CN.DATASET.TRAIN_POSE_ROOT = None  # (optional directory for poses)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\loftr\lib\site-packages\yacs\config.py", line 155, in __setattr__
    _assert_with_logging(
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\loftr\lib\site-packages\yacs\config.py", line 521, in _assert_with_logging
    assert cond, msg
AssertionError: Invalid type <class 'NoneType'> for key TRAIN_POSE_ROOT; valid types = {<class 'tuple'>, <class 'bool'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'int'>}
```

Following steps in github, I use "bash scripts/reproduce_train/indoor_ds.sh"
This is indoor_ds.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash -l

SCRIPTPATH=$(dirname $(readlink -f "$0"))
PROJECT_DIR="${SCRIPTPATH}/../../"

# conda activate loftr
export PYTHONPATH=$PROJECT_DIR:$PYTHONPATH
cd $PROJECT_DIR

data_cfg_path="configs/data/scannet_trainval.py"
main_cfg_path="configs/loftr/indoor/loftr_ds_dense.py"

n_nodes=1
#n_gpus_per_node=4
n_gpus_per_node=1
#torch_num_workers=4
torch_num_workers=1
batch_size=1
pin_memory=true
exp_name="indoor-ds-bs=$(($n_gpus_per_node * $n_nodes * $batch_size))"

python -u ./train.py \
    ${data_cfg_path} \
    ${main_cfg_path} \
    --exp_name=${exp_name} \
    --gpus=${n_gpus_per_node} --num_nodes=${n_nodes} --accelerator="ddp" \
    --batch_size=${batch_size} --num_workers=${torch_num_workers} --pin_memory=${pin_memory} \
    --check_val_every_n_epoch=1 \
    --log_every_n_steps=100 \
    --flush_logs_every_n_steps=100 \
    --limit_val_batches=1. \
    --num_sanity_val_steps=10 \
    --benchmark=True \
    --max_epochs=30 \
    --parallel_load_data
```

And this is scannet_trainval.py:

```
from configs.data.base import cfg


TRAIN_BASE_PATH = "data/scannet/index"
cfg.DATASET.TRAINVAL_DATA_SOURCE = "ScanNet"
cfg.DATASET.TRAIN_DATA_ROOT = "data/scannet/train"
cfg.DATASET.TRAIN_NPZ_ROOT = f"{TRAIN_BASE_PATH}/scene_data/train"
cfg.DATASET.TRAIN_LIST_PATH = f"{TRAIN_BASE_PATH}/scene_data/train_list/scannet_all.txt"
cfg.DATASET.TRAIN_INTRINSIC_PATH = f"{TRAIN_BASE_PATH}/intrinsics.npz"

TEST_BASE_PATH = "assets/scannet_test_1500"
cfg.DATASET.TEST_DATA_SOURCE = "ScanNet"
cfg.DATASET.VAL_DATA_ROOT = cfg.DATASET.TEST_DATA_ROOT = "data/scannet/test"
cfg.DATASET.VAL_NPZ_ROOT = cfg.DATASET.TEST_NPZ_ROOT = TEST_BASE_PATH
cfg.DATASET.VAL_LIST_PATH = cfg.DATASET.TEST_LIST_PATH = f"{TEST_BASE_PATH}/scannet_test.txt"
cfg.DATASET.VAL_INTRINSIC_PATH = cfg.DATASET.TEST_INTRINSIC_PATH = f"{TEST_BASE_PATH}/intrinsics.npz"
cfg.DATASET.MIN_OVERLAP_SCORE_TEST = 0.0   # for both test and val
```

This is train.py:

```
import math
import argparse
import pprint
from distutils.util import strtobool
from pathlib import Path
from loguru import logger as loguru_logger

import pytorch_lightning as pl
from pytorch_lightning.utilities import rank_zero_only
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import TensorBoardLogger
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateMonitor
from pytorch_lightning.plugins import DDPPlugin

from src.config.default import get_cfg_defaults
from src.utils.misc import get_rank_zero_only_logger, setup_gpus
from src.utils.profiler import build_profiler
from src.lightning.data import MultiSceneDataModule
from src.lightning.lightning_loftr import PL_LoFTR

loguru_logger = get_rank_zero_only_logger(loguru_logger)


def parse_args():
    # init a costum parser which will be added into pl.Trainer parser
    # check documentation: https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/trainer.html#trainer-flags
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument(
        'data_cfg_path', type=str, help='data config path')
    parser.add_argument(
        'main_cfg_path', type=str, help='main config path')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--exp_name', type=str, default='default_exp_name')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--batch_size', type=int, default=4, help='batch_size per gpu')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--num_workers', type=int, default=4)
    parser.add_argument(
        '--pin_memory', type=lambda x: bool(strtobool(x)),
        nargs='?', default=True, help='whether loading data to pinned memory or not')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--ckpt_path', type=str, default=None,
        help='pretrained checkpoint path, helpful for using a pre-trained coarse-only LoFTR')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--disable_ckpt', action='store_true',
        help='disable checkpoint saving (useful for debugging).')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--profiler_name', type=str, default=None,
        help='options: [inference, pytorch], or leave it unset')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--parallel_load_data', action='store_true',
        help='load datasets in with multiple processes.')

    parser = pl.Trainer.add_argparse_args(parser)
    return parser.parse_args()


def main():
    # parse arguments
    args = parse_args()
    rank_zero_only(pprint.pprint)(vars(args))

    # init default-cfg and merge it with the main- and data-cfg
    config = get_cfg_defaults()
    config.merge_from_file(args.main_cfg_path)
    config.merge_from_file(args.data_cfg_path)
    pl.seed_everything(config.TRAINER.SEED)  # reproducibility
    # TODO: Use different seeds for each dataloader workers
    # This is needed for data augmentation

    # scale lr and warmup-step automatically
    args.gpus = _n_gpus = setup_gpus(args.gpus)
    config.TRAINER.WORLD_SIZE = _n_gpus * args.num_nodes
    config.TRAINER.TRUE_BATCH_SIZE = config.TRAINER.WORLD_SIZE * args.batch_size
    _scaling = config.TRAINER.TRUE_BATCH_SIZE / config.TRAINER.CANONICAL_BS
    config.TRAINER.SCALING = _scaling
    config.TRAINER.TRUE_LR = config.TRAINER.CANONICAL_LR * _scaling
    config.TRAINER.WARMUP_STEP = math.floor(config.TRAINER.WARMUP_STEP / _scaling)

    # lightning module
    profiler = build_profiler(args.profiler_name)
    model = PL_LoFTR(config, pretrained_ckpt=args.ckpt_path, profiler=profiler)
    loguru_logger.info(f"LoFTR LightningModule initialized!")

    # lightning data
    data_module = MultiSceneDataModule(args, config)
    loguru_logger.info(f"LoFTR DataModule initialized!")

    # TensorBoard Logger
    logger = TensorBoardLogger(save_dir='logs/tb_logs', name=args.exp_name, default_hp_metric=False)
    ckpt_dir = Path(logger.log_dir) / 'checkpoints'

    # Callbacks
    # TODO: update ModelCheckpoint to monitor multiple metrics
    ckpt_callback = ModelCheckpoint(monitor='auc@10', verbose=True, save_top_k=5, mode='max',
                                    save_last=True,
                                    dirpath=str(ckpt_dir),
                                    filename='{epoch}-{auc@5:.3f}-{auc@10:.3f}-{auc@20:.3f}')
    lr_monitor = LearningRateMonitor(logging_interval='step')
    callbacks = [lr_monitor]
    if not args.disable_ckpt:
        callbacks.append(ckpt_callback)

    # Lightning Trainer
    trainer = pl.Trainer.from_argparse_args(
        args,
        plugins=DDPPlugin(find_unused_parameters=False,
                          num_nodes=args.num_nodes,
                          sync_batchnorm=config.TRAINER.WORLD_SIZE > 0),
        gradient_clip_val=config.TRAINER.GRADIENT_CLIPPING,
        callbacks=callbacks,
        logger=logger,
        sync_batchnorm=config.TRAINER.WORLD_SIZE > 0,
        replace_sampler_ddp=False,  # use custom sampler
        reload_dataloaders_every_epoch=False,  # avoid repeated samples!
        weights_summary='full',
        profiler=profiler)
    loguru_logger.info(f"Trainer initialized!")
    loguru_logger.info(f"Start training!")
    trainer.fit(model, datamodule=data_module)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and this is src/config/default.py:

```
from yacs.config import CfgNode as CN
_CN = CN()

##############  ↓  LoFTR Pipeline  ↓  ##############
_CN.LOFTR = CN()
_CN.LOFTR.BACKBONE_TYPE = 'ResNetFPN'
_CN.LOFTR.RESOLUTION = (8, 2)  # options: [(8, 2), (16, 4)]
_CN.LOFTR.FINE_WINDOW_SIZE = 5  # window_size in fine_level, must be odd
_CN.LOFTR.FINE_CONCAT_COARSE_FEAT = True

# 1. LoFTR-backbone (local feature CNN) config
_CN.LOFTR.RESNETFPN = CN()
_CN.LOFTR.RESNETFPN.INITIAL_DIM = 128
_CN.LOFTR.RESNETFPN.BLOCK_DIMS = [128, 196, 256]  # s1, s2, s3

# 2. LoFTR-coarse module config
_CN.LOFTR.COARSE = CN()
_CN.LOFTR.COARSE.D_MODEL = 256
_CN.LOFTR.COARSE.D_FFN = 256
_CN.LOFTR.COARSE.NHEAD = 8
_CN.LOFTR.COARSE.LAYER_NAMES = ['self', 'cross'] * 4
_CN.LOFTR.COARSE.ATTENTION = 'linear'  # options: ['linear', 'full']
_CN.LOFTR.COARSE.TEMP_BUG_FIX = True

# 3. Coarse-Matching config
_CN.LOFTR.MATCH_COARSE = CN()
_CN.LOFTR.MATCH_COARSE.THR = 0.2
_CN.LOFTR.MATCH_COARSE.BORDER_RM = 2
_CN.LOFTR.MATCH_COARSE.MATCH_TYPE = 'dual_softmax'  # options: ['dual_softmax, 'sinkhorn']
_CN.LOFTR.MATCH_COARSE.DSMAX_TEMPERATURE = 0.1
_CN.LOFTR.MATCH_COARSE.SKH_ITERS = 3
_CN.LOFTR.MATCH_COARSE.SKH_INIT_BIN_SCORE = 1.0
_CN.LOFTR.MATCH_COARSE.SKH_PREFILTER = False
_CN.LOFTR.MATCH_COARSE.TRAIN_COARSE_PERCENT = 0.2  # training tricks: save GPU memory
_CN.LOFTR.MATCH_COARSE.TRAIN_PAD_NUM_GT_MIN = 200  # training tricks: avoid DDP deadlock
_CN.LOFTR.MATCH_COARSE.SPARSE_SPVS = True

# 4. LoFTR-fine module config
_CN.LOFTR.FINE = CN()
_CN.LOFTR.FINE.D_MODEL = 128
_CN.LOFTR.FINE.D_FFN = 128
_CN.LOFTR.FINE.NHEAD = 8
_CN.LOFTR.FINE.LAYER_NAMES = ['self', 'cross'] * 1
_CN.LOFTR.FINE.ATTENTION = 'linear'

# 5. LoFTR Losses
# -- # coarse-level
_CN.LOFTR.LOSS = CN()
_CN.LOFTR.LOSS.COARSE_TYPE = 'focal'  # ['focal', 'cross_entropy']
_CN.LOFTR.LOSS.COARSE_WEIGHT = 1.0
# _CN.LOFTR.LOSS.SPARSE_SPVS = False
# -- - -- # focal loss (coarse)
_CN.LOFTR.LOSS.FOCAL_ALPHA = 0.25
_CN.LOFTR.LOSS.FOCAL_GAMMA = 2.0
_CN.LOFTR.LOSS.POS_WEIGHT = 1.0
_CN.LOFTR.LOSS.NEG_WEIGHT = 1.0
# _CN.LOFTR.LOSS.DUAL_SOFTMAX = False  # whether coarse-level use dual-softmax or not.
# use `_CN.LOFTR.MATCH_COARSE.MATCH_TYPE`

# -- # fine-level
_CN.LOFTR.LOSS.FINE_TYPE = 'l2_with_std'  # ['l2_with_std', 'l2']
_CN.LOFTR.LOSS.FINE_WEIGHT = 1.0
_CN.LOFTR.LOSS.FINE_CORRECT_THR = 1.0  # for filtering valid fine-level gts (some gt matches might fall out of the fine-level window)


##############  Dataset  ##############
_CN.DATASET = CN()
# 1. data config
# training and validating
_CN.DATASET.TRAINVAL_DATA_SOURCE = None  # options: ['ScanNet', 'MegaDepth']
_CN.DATASET.TRAIN_DATA_ROOT = None
_CN.DATASET.TRAIN_POSE_ROOT = None  # (optional directory for poses)
_CN.DATASET.TRAIN_NPZ_ROOT = None
_CN.DATASET.TRAIN_LIST_PATH = None
_CN.DATASET.TRAIN_INTRINSIC_PATH = None
_CN.DATASET.VAL_DATA_ROOT = None
_CN.DATASET.VAL_POSE_ROOT = None  # (optional directory for poses)
_CN.DATASET.VAL_NPZ_ROOT = None
_CN.DATASET.VAL_LIST_PATH = None    # None if val data from all scenes are bundled into a single npz file
_CN.DATASET.VAL_INTRINSIC_PATH = None
# testing
_CN.DATASET.TEST_DATA_SOURCE = None
_CN.DATASET.TEST_DATA_ROOT = None
_CN.DATASET.TEST_POSE_ROOT = None  # (optional directory for poses)
_CN.DATASET.TEST_NPZ_ROOT = None
_CN.DATASET.TEST_LIST_PATH = None   # None if test data from all scenes are bundled into a single npz file
_CN.DATASET.TEST_INTRINSIC_PATH = None

# 2. dataset config
# general options
_CN.DATASET.MIN_OVERLAP_SCORE_TRAIN = 0.4  # discard data with overlap_score < min_overlap_score
_CN.DATASET.MIN_OVERLAP_SCORE_TEST = 0.0
_CN.DATASET.AUGMENTATION_TYPE = None  # options: [None, 'dark', 'mobile']

# MegaDepth options
_CN.DATASET.MGDPT_IMG_RESIZE = 640  # resize the longer side, zero-pad bottom-right to square.
_CN.DATASET.MGDPT_IMG_PAD = True  # pad img to square with size = MGDPT_IMG_RESIZE
_CN.DATASET.MGDPT_DEPTH_PAD = True  # pad depthmap to square with size = 2000
_CN.DATASET.MGDPT_DF = 8

##############  Trainer  ##############
_CN.TRAINER = CN()
_CN.TRAINER.WORLD_SIZE = 1
_CN.TRAINER.CANONICAL_BS = 64
_CN.TRAINER.CANONICAL_LR = 6e-3
_CN.TRAINER.SCALING = None  # this will be calculated automatically
_CN.TRAINER.FIND_LR = False  # use learning rate finder from pytorch-lightning

# optimizer
_CN.TRAINER.OPTIMIZER = "adamw"  # [adam, adamw]
_CN.TRAINER.TRUE_LR = None  # this will be calculated automatically at runtime
_CN.TRAINER.ADAM_DECAY = 0.  # ADAM: for adam
_CN.TRAINER.ADAMW_DECAY = 0.1

# step-based warm-up
_CN.TRAINER.WARMUP_TYPE = 'linear'  # [linear, constant]
_CN.TRAINER.WARMUP_RATIO = 0.
_CN.TRAINER.WARMUP_STEP = 4800

# learning rate scheduler
_CN.TRAINER.SCHEDULER = 'MultiStepLR'  # [MultiStepLR, CosineAnnealing, ExponentialLR]
_CN.TRAINER.SCHEDULER_INTERVAL = 'epoch'    # [epoch, step]
_CN.TRAINER.MSLR_MILESTONES = [3, 6, 9, 12]  # MSLR: MultiStepLR
_CN.TRAINER.MSLR_GAMMA = 0.5
_CN.TRAINER.COSA_TMAX = 30  # COSA: CosineAnnealing
_CN.TRAINER.ELR_GAMMA = 0.999992  # ELR: ExponentialLR, this value for 'step' interval

# plotting related
_CN.TRAINER.ENABLE_PLOTTING = True
_CN.TRAINER.N_VAL_PAIRS_TO_PLOT = 32     # number of val/test paris for plotting
_CN.TRAINER.PLOT_MODE = 'evaluation'  # ['evaluation', 'confidence']
_CN.TRAINER.PLOT_MATCHES_ALPHA = 'dynamic'

# geometric metrics and pose solver
_CN.TRAINER.EPI_ERR_THR = 5e-4  # recommendation: 5e-4 for ScanNet, 1e-4 for MegaDepth (from SuperGlue)
_CN.TRAINER.POSE_GEO_MODEL = 'E'  # ['E', 'F', 'H']
_CN.TRAINER.POSE_ESTIMATION_METHOD = 'RANSAC'  # [RANSAC, DEGENSAC, MAGSAC]
_CN.TRAINER.RANSAC_PIXEL_THR = 0.5
_CN.TRAINER.RANSAC_CONF = 0.99999
_CN.TRAINER.RANSAC_MAX_ITERS = 10000
_CN.TRAINER.USE_MAGSACPP = False

# data sampler for train_dataloader
_CN.TRAINER.DATA_SAMPLER = 'scene_balance'  # options: ['scene_balance', 'random', 'normal']
# 'scene_balance' config
_CN.TRAINER.N_SAMPLES_PER_SUBSET = 200
_CN.TRAINER.SB_SUBSET_SAMPLE_REPLACEMENT = True  # whether sample each scene with replacement or not
_CN.TRAINER.SB_SUBSET_SHUFFLE = True  # after sampling from scenes, whether shuffle within the epoch or not
_CN.TRAINER.SB_REPEAT = 1  # repeat N times for training the sampled data
# 'random' config
_CN.TRAINER.RDM_REPLACEMENT = True
_CN.TRAINER.RDM_NUM_SAMPLES = None

# gradient clipping
_CN.TRAINER.GRADIENT_CLIPPING = 0.5

# reproducibility
# This seed affects the data sampling. With the same seed, the data sampling is promised
# to be the same. When resume training from a checkpoint, it's better to use a different
# seed, otherwise the sampled data will be exactly the same as before resuming, which will
# cause less unique data items sampled during the entire training.
# Use of different seed values might affect the final training result, since not all data items
# are used during training on ScanNet. (60M pairs of images sampled during traing from 230M pairs in total.)
_CN.TRAINER.SEED = 66


def get_cfg_defaults():
    """Get a yacs CfgNode object with default values for my_project."""
    # Return a clone so that the defaults will not be altered
    # This is for the "local variable" use pattern
    return _CN.clone()
```

My question is: Do I need to modify default.py since some variable is set to None?(Notice that some path has been set in scannet_trainval.py)
The whole project is open in github : https://github.com/zju3dv/LoFTR

Comment: What version of `yacs` do you have installed?  It seems [LoFTR needs at least version 0.1.8](https://github.com/zju3dv/LoFTR/blob/master/requirements.txt).  Support for `None` in `yacs` configuration values was only added in version 0.1.8 of yacs (see [GitHub PR #18](https://github.com/rbgirshick/yacs/pull/18)).

Comment: Yes, I have installed yacs == 0.1.8